# ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined while including html file (with JS and CSS ) into other html file

Tags: arrays, html, highcharts, include

I am trying to include one html file (with JSS and CSS code embedded in HTML) into other html file using following code.

File a.html

```
<html>
  <head> 
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("mychart2.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head>

  <body>
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**File mycharts2.html**

http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/585768/mychart2-html.html

After using developer tool, i found following error:

**ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined

jquery-1.9.1.js line 603 > eval:4**

and there is no output. How can i fix this issue?

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? Is mychart2.html in the same directory as a.html?

Comment: Yes it is in same directory.

Comment: have you given proper file name.

Comment: YOu need to attach reference to highcharts.js in the header of mainfile.

Answer (score 1):

After downloading your html file and taking a look at the code. I believe your issue is the following line:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
```

According to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-ajax/) highcharts demo I found on jsfiddle. You have the initialization of highcharts incorrect. The code should look like this:

```
$('#chart116319a1dae9').highcharts({data:...,otherStuff:...});
```

I highly recommend taking a look at the HighCharts site and taking a look at their [Demos](http://www.highcharts.com/demo)

Comment: In order to share my files, I uploaded my file to megafileupload but it adds .html extention to existing file but original was having .html extention. So this issue is not because of file extention.

Comment: In the javascript console do you have any errors? Either that file doesn't exist or you don't have access to the file.

Comment: I am newbie to javascript, so don't know how to use console.

Comment: In chrome / firefox. Open your page, then press F12. Click on the console tab. What errors are displayed?

Comment: No Error at all but when i click on line it says script { display:none;} what does this mean?

Comment: @user15662 as the content of `script` is never visible on a page and because the `script` tag should not influence the layout it has `display: none` as default style. I highly suggest to learn the basics of `html`, `css`, `js` and the developer tools.

Comment: I have updated my question with error message after using Developer tool.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check above @user15662